# Comparing the word-counts of two files, accounting for the number of occurrences

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm currently working on a program which is supposed to find exploits for vulnerabilities in web-applications by looking at the "Document Object Model" (DOM) of the application.

One approach for narrowing down the number of possible DB-entries follows the strategy of further filtering the entries by comparing the word-count of the DOM and the database entry.

I already have two dicts (actually Dataframes, but showing dict here for better presentation), each containing the top 10 words in descending order of their numbers of ocurrences in the text.

```py
word_count_dom = {"Peter": 10, "is": 6, "eating": 2, ...}

word_count_db = {"eating": 6, "is": 6, "Peter": 1, "breakfast": 1, ...}
```

Now i would like to calculate some kind of value, which represents how similar the two dicts are while accounting for the number of occurences.

Currently im using:

```py
len([value in word_count_db for value in word_count_dom])

>>> 3
```

but this does not account for the number of occurrences at all.

Looking at the example i would like the program to give more value to the "is"-match, because of the generally better "Ranking-Position to Number of Occurences"-value.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea:
Compute for each dict the relative probability of each entry to occur (e.g. among all the top counts "Peter" occurs 20% of the time). Do this for each word occuring in either dict. And then use something like:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhattacharyya_distance

Comment: Thx for the suggestion, i will try to figure this solution out and will post an update on it, as soon as i get sth working